# Set Yesterday BATCH FILE

Tags: batch-file, cmd

If this gives me today's date...

```
SET TODAY=%date:~7,2%.%date:~-10,2%.%date:~-4,4%
```

...how can i get yesterday's date? Can I get it in the same style?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of the three variables in the 3rd last line to suit you:

```
:: yesterdays date
@echo off
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "date-yesterday=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%"

echo Yesterday was "%date-yesterday%"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I wrote to do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

Call :GetDateTime Year Month Day
Call :SubtractDate %Year% %Month% %Day% -1 Ret
echo %Ret%
pause


:SubtractDate Year Month Day <+/-Days> Ret
::Adapted from DosTips Functions::
setlocal & set a=%4
set "yy=%~1"&set "mm=%~2"&set "dd=%~3"
set /a "yy=10000%yy% %%10000,mm=100%mm% %% 100,dd=100%dd% %% 100"
if %yy% LSS 100 set /a yy+=2000 &rem Adds 2000 to two digit years
set /a JD=dd-32075+1461*(yy+4800+(mm-14)/12)/4+367*(mm-2-(mm-14)/12*12)/12-3*((yy+4900+(mm-14)/12)/100)/4
if %a:~0,1% equ + (set /a JD=%JD%+%a:~1%) else set /a JD=%JD%-%a:~1%
set /a L= %JD%+68569,     N= 4*L/146097, L= L-(146097*N+3)/4, I= 4000*(L+1)/1461001
set /a L= L-1461*I/4+31, J= 80*L/2447,  K= L-2447*J/80,      L= J/11
set /a J= J+2-12*L,      I= 100*(N-49)+I+L
set /a YYYY= I, MM=100+J, DD=100+K
set MM=%MM:~-2% & set DD=%DD:~-2%
set ret=%DD: =%.%MM: =%.%YYYY: =%
endlocal & set %~5=%ret%
exit /b

:GetDateTime Year Month Day Hour Minute Second
@echo off & setlocal
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
( ENDLOCAL
     IF "%~1" NEQ "" set "%~1=%YYYY%" 
     IF "%~2" NEQ "" set "%~2=%MM%" 
     IF "%~3" NEQ "" set "%~3=%DD%"
     IF "%~4" NEQ "" set "%~4=%HH%" 
     IF "%~5" NEQ "" set "%~5=%Min%"
     IF "%~6" NEQ "" set "%~6=%Sec%"
)
exit /b
```