# Create a task which will expire/disable after sixmonth from its start date

Tags: cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I want to create a windows task which will run a batch file every day at 12.00am for only six months from the day the task is created. I'm using following command to create a task. I'm not sure how to set expiration date so that the task will stop executing after six months.

My command is:

`schtasks /create /sc Daily /mo 10 /tn run /tr "C:\Users\Rashmi\test.bat" /st 00.00`

Answer (score 1):

get the help of Powershell to easily calculate the enddate (it's generaly possible with pure batch, but it's a nightmare):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell "(get-date).AddMonths(+6).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')"') do set "enddate=%%a"
schtasks /create /sc Daily /mo 10 /tn run /tr "C:\Users\Rashmi\test.bat" /st 00.00 /ED %enddate%
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376408/set-yesterday-batch-file) for a pure batch solution and a solution using VBS instead of Powershell (but needs a temporary file).

Comment: I ran the above command but I'm getting date format should be in MM/DD/YYYY format error. I changed the format in the double quotes to MM.DD.YYYYY instead of 'dd.MM.yyyy but it didn't help. I'm new to the powershell scripting. Do you have any suggestion on how to fix it

Comment: ERROR: Invalid End Date (Date should be in "mm/dd/yyyy" format).
22/10/2018

Comment: then it's `'MM/dd/yyyy'` (edited my answer). Sorry, my (German) `schtasks /?` shows me the German date format. (note: don't use `mm`, as Powershell will interpret that as "minutes")

Comment: Yes I tried changing the date format the way you suggested in your reply, but it is giving me the same error:

Comment: Hi Stephen...thanks for your reply.I think there is nothing wrong with the date format. The end date is not accepting mm/dd/yyyy format for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

You want a /ed parameter and to establish the value dynamically using the %date% value

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks#BKMK_create

Comment: I'm struggling in calculating the /ed parameter.

Comment: Assuming your locale is one which requires the day before month (that article states which need which format) then use the following: %date:~0,2%/%date:~3,2%/%date:~6,4%

Comment: If your locale needs month 1st, then swap the 1st and 2nd values

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your reply. I adopted the Stephen solution since it was easy to follow.

Comment: @BlythMeister See [Answering:provide context for links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) **rash** If you adopt an answer you should [check](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or upvote it.

Comment: Could you please explain or provide a code example? Consider that the URL might become broken in future...

Comment: I have, I explained to use the /ed parameter which takes a date.